# What is the problem in this code and how is this possible to write -3 index to an array. Like : y[-3] = 1st digit of ID number?

Tags: matlab

For this function:
y(t) =(sum from -inf to +inf) y[n]*p(t-nTs)

I wrote :

```
%main function
function project(arr,n,t,Ts)
   symsum(arr(n)*p(t,-n*Ts),n,-inf,inf)
end

function rValue = p(t,Ts)
   %standard square pulse of duration Ts:
   if t<=(Ts/2)&& t>=(-Ts/2)
      rValue = 1;
      return
   %standard triangular pulse of duration 2Ts:    
   elseif t<=Ts && t>=-Ts
      rValue = (1-(abs(t)/Ts));
      return
   %truncated ideal pulse:
   elseif t <=(3*Ts) && t>=(3*Ts)
      rValue = sin(pi*t/Ts)/(pi*t/Ts);
      return
   %a pulse signal consisting of three parabolic segments
   elseif t==no idea
      rValue = no idea; 
      return
   else
      rValue = 0;
      return
   end
end
```

after function I have to create an array but what the assignment wants is like y[-3] . How is this possible to write -3 index to an array. Like :

```
y[-3] = 1st digit of ID number (leftmost digit)
y[-2] = -2nd digit of ID number
y[-1] = 0
y[0] = 3rd digit of ID number
y[1] = -4th digit of ID number
y[2] = 5th digit of ID number
y[3] = 0
y[4] = -6th digit of ID number
y[5] = 7th digit of ID number
y[6] = 8th digit of ID number (rightmost digit)
y[n] = 0 otherwise (-inf < n < inf)
```

Comment: If `y` is 0 elsewhere you can take the sum only from `n = -3` to `n = 6`.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need something that can be indexed using negative numbers you can use key-map pairs. Unfortunately, this method requires you to index using a `char` indicated by the single quotes `''`. I would advise against typically indexing with negatives but this may help in your case. Also, you can evaluate this summation from the range `n = -3` to `n = 6` since the multiplication everywhere else outside that range is effectively zero.

### Key-Map Pairs:

```
Keys = {'-3','-2','-1','0','1','2','3','4','5','6'};
Digits = [1 -2 0 3 -4 5 0 -6 7 8];
y = containers.Map(Keys,Digit);

y('-3')
y('-2')
y('-1')
y('0') 
y('1')
y('2')
y('3')
y('4')
y('5')
y('6')
```

### Alternatively by Using Anonymous Functions:

Thanks to **@Hoki** for this amazing alternative solution. It remaps the negative indices by using an anonymous function.

```
y = [1 -2 0 3 -4 5 0 -6 7 8];

idx = @(n) n+4;

y(idx(-3))
y(idx(-2))
y(idx(-1))
y(idx(0))
y(idx(1))
y(idx(2))
y(idx(3))
y(idx(4))
y(idx(5))
y(idx(6))
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: or you can use an anonimous conversion function: `idx=@(n) n+4`. Then you have to not forget to use the function to index into your array: `y(idx(-3))` ... `y(idx(-2))` ... etc ...

Comment: @Hoki Very true that's a good way to handle it as well.

Comment: I wrote it here so you can add it to your answer as an alternative option (if you want to of course). I didn't think it was worth an answer by itself.